# MCR (MATLAB compiler runtime) with Image processing toolbox

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu

I'm trying to deploy an application from MATLAB to JAVA. 
I create my jar file from MATLAB R2011a with the deploytool on Windows 7.

I also installed MCR r2011a on Ubuntu, and set environment variable as follow.

```
## MATLAB compiler Runtime (MCR) 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
export XAPPLRESDIR=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/X11/app-defaults
```

When I run my jar file on the Ubuntu, I got these error:

```
com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWException:
Undefined function or method 'imresizemex' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.

Error in ==> TextDetect at 78
Error in ==> imresize at 169
Error in ==> imresize>resizeAlongDim at 792
```

I got the same problem when I call the function in image processing toolbox, such as `imresize`, `dilate`, etc.

If anyone has a solution about this problem, please give me a hint.

Comment: The problem is the original matlab relies on a mex routine, imresizemex, which means it is a compiled, architecture-dependent binary (a DLL on windows, something like a imresizemex.mexa64 dynamic library on Ubuntu). For whatever reason, it's either not in the Ubuntu runtime, or it's not being found. Maybe `find /usr/local/MATLAB -name "imresizemex.*"` from the Ubuntu terminal, and if it's found, make sure that directory is in your library path?

Comment: Thanks for your replying ,@dpwe ! 
But I cannot find any imresizemex.* file.
how can I get imresizemex ? do I need to reinstall mcr again?
do you have any solution about this. 
thanks again :)

Comment: sorry, I just found it in the hidden folder of home directory.
how to check my library path ? thanks ! 

./.mcrCache7.15/mtrss_1/toolbox/images/images/private/imresizemex_mexw64.auth
./.mcrCache7.15/mtrss_1/toolbox/images/images/private/imresizemex.mexw64
./.mcrCache7.15/mtrss_1/toolbox/images/images/imresize.m
./tmpFolder/mtrss_1/toolbox/images/images/private/imresizemex_mexw64.auth
./tmpFolder/mtrss_1/toolbox/images/images/private/imresizemex.mexw64
./tmpFolder/mtrss_1/toolbox/images/images/imresize.m

Comment: The version you found is the 64 bit Windows binary, so it won't run under linux.  I guess Mathworks only supports exporting executables on the same architecture that you plan to run on.  Java *ought* to support cross-platform execution, but here the routine also relies on platform-specific binaries.  These are being included in your package for Windows64, but not for other platforms.  You could try pulling `imresizemex.mexa64` from some other machine and putting it in e.g. `/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/runtime/glnxa64`, but I'm not that optimistic.  Maybe ask on mathworks.com.

Comment: I am very appreciation for your help! Thank you very much! 
I'll post my question on mathwork ! :)